# Swift enum does not have a member named 'rawValue' when declare a variable as optional value

Tags: swift, enums, xcode6

I'm looking the Swift Programming Language, and I faced an issue, I coudln't distinguish whether it's the Lauguage's issue or not(I'm using Xcode Version 6.1 (6A1052c)):

```
enum Rank: Int {
    case Ace = 1
    case Two, Three, Four, Five
    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .Ace: return "Ace"
        default: return String(self.rawValue)
        }
    }
}

var rank: Rank?
rank = Rank(rawValue: 2)
println(rank.rawValue)
```

in the last line, it throws an error: `'Rank?' does not have a member named`rawValue``

but if a declare the variable like `var rank: Rank`, and modify `rank = Rank(rawValue: 2)` to `rank = Rank(rawValue: 2)!`, it can pass and no error arised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiating an enum from a rawValue returns an optional of that enum, `Rank?` in your case. In order to access the properties of the optional enum, you have to unwrap it, to get a `Rank`.

```
var rank: Rank?
rank = Rank(rawValue: 2)
if(rank != nil){
    println(rank!.rawValue)
}
```

You can also have Rank be typed as `Rank` instead of `Rank?`

```
var rank: Rank
rank = Rank(rawValue: 2)! //make sure you know this will always return a Rank. If it's nil your program will crash
println(rank.rawValue)
```